# NHibernate SchemaExport With Abstract Class Lists Not Being Created

Tags: .net, nhibernate, list, abstract, schemaexport

I am currently trying to create a base class for my domain objects that contains a list because we have to model an excel spreadsheet with very particular requirements.

My classes look like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass : EntityBase
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        PersonnelList = new List<Person>();
    }
    public virtual IList<AuditPersonnel> PersonnelList { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Details { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public virtual DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the schema export function to create the database the list relationship is not created in the database tables.

Is this even possible?  Should I be using the SubClass method on my mappings to create these classes in a single table?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the abstract from the BaseClass and using multi-table inheritance and that has worked out well.